# Auto updating (time) tooltip in Griffon SystemTray

Tags: groovy, java, griffon

Hey,
I'm thinking about using griffon in an very simple DeskTop app I've been asked to code. 90% of it's features are a few mouse clicks away from the system tray, it's like "start/choose/stop". One thing I'd need is an tooltip, that would update it's content each second (or minute, nevermind ;-)) counting the time someone has been working on some particular task.

My questions are:

- How can I make the "Youre working for: ${HourMin.since model.startedWorkingAt}" be called on an regular basis, to make the tootip always up to date? Using this code, it only gets called once, at tooltip construction time.
- How can I dynamically add "actions" to the popupMenu during the application lifetime?

Thanks for any advice - book advices where such problems are solved would be also quite helpful.

```
actions {
  action(id: 'cutAction',
          name: 'Pokaż okno',
          closure: {
            trayIcon.displayMessage("Cut", "Cut some content", NONE)
          },
          mnemonic: 'T',
          accelerator: shortcut('X'),
          smallIcon: imageIcon(resource: "icons/cut.png", class: Console),
          shortDescription: 'Cut'
  )
//... more actions
}

systemTray {
  trayIcon(id: "trayIcon",
          resource: "/groovy/ui/ConsoleIcon.png",
          class: groovy.ui.Console,
          toolTip: {
            "Youre working for: ${HourMin.since model.startedWorkingAt}"
          },
          actionPerformed: {
//            todo do toggle
          }) {
    popupMenu {
      menuItem(cutAction)
      menuItem(copyAction)
      menuItem(pasteAction)
      separator()
      menuItem(exitAction)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an way to do it, here's how:

```
// in the controller
def updateSystemTimeTask = new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  void run() {
    onSystemTimeUpdate System.currentTimeMillis()
  }
}

def onSystemTimeUpdate(Long systemTime) {
  if (model.working) {
    view.systemTray.trayIcons[0].toolTip = "Pracujesz już ${HourMin.since model.startedWorkingAt}".toString()
  } else {
    view.systemTray.trayIcons[0].toolTip = = "Obecnie nie pracujesz."
  }
}

// ant this in the initialization method
def myTimer = new Timer().schedule updateSystemTimeTask, initialDelay, minute
```

I'm not sure if it's the cleanest way possible, but it's quite ok I guess, since all the action is in the views controller anyways.

Comment: Ok this addresses something that I hadn't considered in my previous answer.  There is no source to generate the event.  Creating the timer creates that source of event.  The one tweak to make it 'cleaner' would be to have the timer action update a 'timeSpentWorling' field in the model and have the view bind to that field.  That way you are not directly manipulating the view.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll look into this idea. The event could be generated in an service right?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried binding the GString?

```
toolTip: bind {
        "Youre working for: ${HourMin.since model.startedWorkingAt}"
      },
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Sadly that didn't get the job done. I figured out an way to do it though, see bellow :-)

Comment: another tweak:   bind { model.startedWorkingAt; "<old GString>" }